# Printing a bitstream data /TCP related

Tags: c, pointers, tcp

I am trying to make a communication between a Client and a Sever through TCP.

Let's say the client send 10 Hex numbers as bitstream to Sever. `send(socketID, pSend, 20, 0);` Where `pSend = &ArrayClient;` and `unsigned short ArrayClient[] = { 0A, 0B, BA, B1...., FA }`.

The sever receive the bytes stream with `recv(acceptID, pRecv, 20, 0)`. How can I print out the content in my pointer `pRecv` correctly. As Sever I won't know how many bytes did the Client send, therefore I don't know how many to print.
Because the datas were sent as bitstream, not a string. I can not know the end of the message by finding `\0` like working with string.

So is there a way that I can know how many bytes that I received as sever, or any way to print out the bitstream in my `pRecv` as Hex numbers.

I have tried pointer to a pointer and something similar like this:

```
while( ((unsigned int*)pRecv)[i] != 0){
    printf("%X", ((unsigned int*)pRecv)[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: The recv() function returns a value. (the number of bytes received, or -1) ANd you *cannot* know how many bytes were sent; you can only know how many you received. You can only know how many bytes to expect if client and server use some kind of protocol or convention. (such as sending fixed length, or sending the length first, or sending a delimiter after every *message*)

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with TCP, there is no built-in way of separating messages, so your protocol needs to delimit the message boundaries in some known way.

A simple way of doing this is by first sending single byte denoting the length of the message, then sending that number of bytes.

For example, before sending the above message, do this:

```
char mlen = 20;
send(socketID, &mlen, 1, 0);
```

Comment: notice that you will next get into byte ordering issues, either for the length or the payload. Me I would send text rather than binary. Fixed size ascii length, then json payload

Comment: yes. I am aware of this. My exercise have 2 part. I am in part 1 where I have to send the data "raw and naive". Which mean sending without handling the length of the incoming message. Building boundaries and not letting all the messages mashing together is part 2. And I want to send the message as text but my prof. does not allow that.